# VPS not resolving DNS names

Tags: centos, dns

I have a CentOS 6 VPS. I can ping `8.8.8.8` but not `google.com`.

My `resolv.conf` is:

```
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 4.2.2.4
```

Is there anything else that I should check?

Update:

```
# dig @8.8.8.8 google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.30.rc1.el6_6.3 <<>> @8.8.8.8 google.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

# iptables -L -n 
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: was it working before? iptables, corporate firewall, firewall of your VPS provider? You could listen/debug port 53 with tcpdump. The post is very scant in details.

Comment: If it is installed, you can use the `dig` command to gather more information about the problem. For example, to direct a query at a specific DNS server, try something like `dig @8.8.8.8 google.com`.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Yes, It was working before (a month ago). `-bash: tcpdump: command not found` How should I use tcpdump?

Comment: firewall/routing problems. What´s the output of `iptables -L -n`

Comment: not your own apparently by the ouput...do you have a web panel where you can define firewall rules?

Comment: No, there is not such panel.

Comment: Does the provider forces you to use their own DNS nowadays and has firewall rules that do not allow others?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Oh, I guess they had sent a notification regarding DNS changes. Let me tale a look at that.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro The provider had asked to use a particular dns ips. using that resolved the issue. How did you find out that? Thank a lot.

Comment: Because it is common practice. I will detail it better.

Comment: Actually because you had it working before AND it being a common practice.

Comment: I am quite finished editing the answer, and whilst I do find a lot of tutorials detailing how to configure firewalls, I did not find any link justifying the policy. Well, this will be one for starters. Would you mark the answer as correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As found out debugging the issue together with the original poster, the problem of DNS failing to resolve is that the VPS provider instated and warned previously about a policy obliging to use an internal DNS address, blocking the use of alternatives in their firewall.

As the OP had the email of the provider warning of the change, it was not necessary to do further debugging to confirm the suspicion.

It is rather common practice to force hosted services or servers to use internal DNS servers, to best monitor the usage, enabling earlier detection of compromised machines doing DNS denial of service attacks, to track better customer problems, give them access to special services, applying policies at DNS level (anti-malware, others), do request rate control, and even statistics.

Often malware also changes the default DNS servers of compromised hosts, and this infra-structure setup does not allow that.

Even without forcing all the customers to change addresses, firewall rules can be done, and are more often configured in VPN services and at corporate level to redirect all the traffic to external DNS servers to an internal one.

I would also add that often, as a current practice in the industry, while internal DNS are forced in customers in the lower tiers of service, it can happen that changing to higher tiers (e.g. paying more), that restriction is lifted.